# Rules of the methods of the activity lifecycle

Tags: java, android, android-activity, lifecycle

Is there any rules for what, and what to not put in onresume, onpause, onstart etc?

Thanks in advance. Petter Daae

Comment: i'm not understand you , please more details

Comment: Some help : this link has an "Activity lifecycle" category, you may like to read it : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link below should answer all your questions

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: No problem that's the android documentation